# Set value in useState after redux dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

My axios transaction is all done in the redux actions so that I can re-use the function. The issue is that, I need to fetch the data first which is done by redux and then re-assign the value in a state, but the data cannot be populated in the state. Below is how my code looks like.

**Setting.js**

```
...
import { getUserDetail } from './redux/actions/settingActions';

export default function Setting() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { user } = useSelector(state => state.settingReducer)
    const [userDetail, setUserDetail] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getUserDetail())
        setUserDetail(user)     // I want to set the user here
    }, [])

    ...
}
```

**settingActions.js**

```
export const getUserDetail = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    axios.get('url-goes-here')
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: SET_USER_DETAIL,
            payload: { res.data }
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
        throw error;
    })
}
```

**settingReducer**

```
function initialState() {
    return {
        ...
        user: {}
    }
}

export default function (state = initialState(), action) {
    const { type, payload } = action;
    switch (type) {
        case SET_USER_DETAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

My purpose of doing this is because I want to do some user details update but I want it to be done within the same file.

Comment: Why would you need `userDetail` in the component state at all if you are already selecting `user` from redux?

Comment: Like I said in my post, I want to use it for the details update but at the same time I don't want to go through with the redux since I used it for a different purpose.

Comment: Got it.  You're storing pending changes in local state, but you want to set the initial value based on the fetched value.

Comment: Exactly! I ended up using two useEffect. One with empty array `[]` and one with `[user]`. So in my first useEffect I do the dispatch and set back the value in a state at the second useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

put user and dispatch as dependency in useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getUserDetail())
        setUserDetail(user)     
    }, [user,dispatch])
```

Comment: If I do this the user will keep on triggering the useEffect every milliseconds and making the application hang.

Comment: It will only trigger when value user of changes.

Comment: Yes but for some reason it keeps on triggering the useEffect although there is no changes. If I remove it, it will only trigger once. Could it be the redux?

Comment: I believe that the redux store is changing every time after a dispatch and the useEffect reading user as a new value. Hence, it's causing a nonstop effect.

Comment: @Emerald, mate did you fixed it? I am searching for the same solution.